# Unable to get redirect URI from Google Developer console

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-developers-console

I am trying to build a cross-platform Xamarin.Forms application using Xamarin.Auth to sign in via Google. I have got two client IDs (one for iOS one for Android) from the site and every web tutorial I can find to do this says I will find a redirect URI with the other credentials in my Google Developer console. This is NOT the case, I do NOT have the option to generate or even set a redirect URI for the key, and I cannot find one anywhere and this is prohibiting me from moving forward with the project. Any ideas on where I can go with this? I need to get some form of external sign in working, with any provider at this stage, ASAP - the eventual plan is to link this with an Amazon DynamoDB so that users can store and access their data.

EDIT: I now have this, was unaware that I had to reverse the client ID string. However I am now left with the problem of when I log in, it logs in but I get a webpage not available with UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME error - how do I get this to go back to the app, authenticated and working?